# Difference between two seemingly similar regular expressions in MySQL - identical outputs

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have been trying to teach myself MySQL, and was wondering if somebody could please explain the difference between the use of the regex metacharacters '*' and '?'. The book I am using describes them both as "matching (0) or one instances of the strings preceding it". I tried using both while looking for the same thing in a practice table I created and got exactly the same output, so if one of the operators is supposed to be greedy and the other not, it doesn't look like that is always the case with every table.

Edit 1: I'm including a screenshot of the output I got from '*' [that shows it matching a statement of the form 'ax*' to just a.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KytGh.jpg)

Edit 2: regex101.com does not list MySQL as a "flavor" and when I try to do 'al*' to Alexandra there, it says no match for any of the flavors. Is the fact that MySQL Workbench is returning Alexandra as one of the outputs something specific to MySQL that does not apply to any of these other languages?

Comment: It's time to leave this book and try https://regex101.com/ for regex. They have an explanation of written regex and description of the meanings of each part

Comment: The expression `"al*"` will match anything with a lower case "a", which is what your output shows.  The `"*"` applies only to the `l`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I see now! So, it's not matching it to the "Al" at the beginning of "Alexandra", it is matching it to the "a" at the end!

Answer (score 0):

They are not quite the same.  `"*"` means "0 or more".  `"?"` means "0 or 1", like "optional".  So, given "ax*b" and "ax?b":

- Neither will match "a"
- Both will match "ab"
- Both will match "axb"
- Only the first will match "axxb" or "axxxxxxb"

Comment: so was that a misprint? Also, it looks like from the output I got that both will also match just "a". I looked at a list of names and searched for names with 'Al*' and 'Al?'. Both gave me names with just A's and no l's in them in addition to names with both 'Al' in that order and in reverse order.

Comment: If the book says `"*"` matches 0 or one instances, then it is wrong.  And the regex `"ax*b"` will not match the lone string "a".

Comment: If you want to play with this, try a web site like https://regex101.com/ .  You enter your expression plus some sample text, and it shows you the result.   (As @astentx already suggested, I see.)

Comment: in Python, I'd agree with you. But I found that it did happen in MySQL. I don't know if it's something peculiar to MySQL that allows that to happen.

Comment: You're using "rlike"?  That should require a match for the entire pattern.  If you have an example, you might add it to your question.

Comment: I added a screenshot to my original question. You have to click the link to see it.